# Append components inside other component in Vue JS

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to make a simple "Load More" function for posts using Vue JS but when I try to append new posts, the previous ones are removed.

This is my PostWallComponent, which is supposed to hold all posts (`<post-item-component>`).

I fetch first 4 posts from the DB, store them in `this.posts` and then I send them using the `v-for` loop to `<post-item-component>`.

Then when someone clicks on the "More" button I call `getPosts()` function where I fetch another 4 posts from the DB. Here comes my problem - I store these new posts inside `this.posts` and I try to append them to the post container. They do append but the previous 4 get deleted from the container.

I think I know what is wrong - at line `this.posts = response.data` I replace old posts with new ones but I don't know how to append new ones without removing old ones. I tried to `push()` new posts to the array but that turned into a big mess (repetitive posts in the container).

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="post_container">
            <post-item-component v-for="post in this.posts"
                 v-bind:cuid="cuid"
                 v-bind:auid="auid"
                 v-bind:post="post"
                 v-bind:key="post.id">
            </post-item-component>
            <button type="button" @click="getPosts">More</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import PostItemComponent from "./PostItemComponent";

export default {
    props: ['init_place', 'init_type', 'current_user_id', 'active_user'],
    components: {
        PostItemComponent
    },
    data() {
        return {
            place: this.init_place,
            type: this.init_type,
            cuid: this.current_user_id,
            auid: this.active_user,
            limit: 4,
            offset: 0,
            posts: [],
        };
    },
    mounted() {
        console.log('Component mounted.');
        this.getPosts();
    },
    methods: {
        getPosts() {
            console.log('post');
            axios.get('/p/fetch', {
                params: {
                    place: this.place,
                    type: this.type,
                    cuid: this.cuid,
                    auid: this.auid,
                    offset: this.offset,
                    limit: this.limit,
                }
            })
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log(response);
                    this.posts = response.data;
                    this.offset = this.limit;
                    this.limit += 4;

                })
            .catch(function (error) {
                //currentObj.output = error;
            });
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

In case someone wonders:

- cuid is current user id = ID of user whose profile I opened
- auid is active user ID = logged in user ID

`<post-item-component>` is just couple of divs displaying post header, body etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could also use `this.posts = this.posts.concat(response.data)`

the problem is that the `Array.push()` method does not work with vue reactivity. For that you need to replace the whole array. As one proposed solution, you could use the spread operator to achieve this as so:

```
this.posts = [...this.posts, ...response.data];
```

This is replacing the whole array with a new array that is combining the old items with the fetched ones by spreading each of the array elements into the new array.

You can see an example here:
[codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-goldwasser-j6czm?file=/src/App.vue)